# Changing mutable class into immutable

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, design-patterns, shared-libraries

I'm facing an architecture decision which I need some help.

I'm creating a library that will be used by several clients. In this library I have a class named `LibClass` with a read-write property named `aProperty` and also class named `LibManager` which holds a reference to a `Libclass` instance. `LibManager` is responsible to update `LibClass` properties.

The clients can get the `LibClass` instance via a method on `LibManager`, let's call it `getLibClassInstanceMethod`.

I don't want my clients to have the ability to change `aProperty` in `LibClass` as this means that the clients can change my library model. I only want `LibManager` to have access changing `aProperty`.

I've been contemplating with several solutions:

***option 1***

inside `getLibClassInstanceMethod` return deep copy of the object.

**Pros:**
I'm always sure that only the library has full access to the model.

**Cons:**
Memory consumption - each time I want to get the object, I need to clone it.

***option 2***

Making the `LibClass` immutable; Every time I want to make a change to the class properties, I need to create a new class and in the designated initializer(constructor) pass the new values and the destroy the old object.

**Pros:**
I make the class become immutable which is exactly what I want

Cons:
When classes become big it's a little weird to always re create classes just because one property changed.

***option 3***

Creating some sort of mutable/immutable pair like NSString/NSMutableString.

**Pros:**
Not sure

**Cons:**
For each class there's need to be two counterparts which double the number of classes.

I'm really not sure which path to go. What would you do?

Thanks

Comment: I like 3 option, but you can also make LibClass immutable and create separate class to modify it like LibEditor. For the first time you can always re-create LibClass (implementation inside LibEditor), which you want to edit, but after you can change implementation to more efficient

Comment: Just don't expose the setters. ie because you're working on objC you are in complete control of what you declare in your header.  So just keep the setters private, and expose only the getters so that these properties appear to be read-only to clients

Comment: Jef, `LibManager` needs to have access, therefore I can't make it readonly.

Comment: I didn't say make it read-only, I said make it APPEAR to be read only to clients. Make a private header/extension/category which exposes the setters for your libManager ;)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is as Jef says.

In LibClass.h inside the interface:

```
@property (strong, readonly) id aProperty;
```

In a new file LibClassPrivate.h:

```
@interface LibClass ()
@property (strong, readwrite) id aPropertyWritable;
@end
```

In LibClass.m:

```
@implementation LibClass{
    id _aProperty;
}

- (id) aProperty{
    return [_aProperty copy];
}

- (void) setAPropertyWritable: (id) aPropertyWritable {
    _aProperty = aPropertyWritable;
}
- (id) aPropertyWritable{
    return _aProperty;
}
@end
```

Basically, we have two properties. Both are backed by one instance variable. The one revealed in our public header can only return a copy of the ivar. The one revealed in our private header can read and write the ivar. Whatever classes need to be able to use the read and write accessors can just `#import` the private header into their .m file.

Just make sure that whatever type of object _aProperty is implements copyWithZone:.

By the way, even Apple mentions this method.

> If you intend to make “private” methods or properties available to
>   select other classes, such as related classes within a framework, you
>   can declare the class extension in a separate header file and import
>   it in the source files that need it. It’s not uncommon to have two
>   header files for a class, for example, such as XYZPerson.h and
>   XYZPersonPrivate.h. When you release the framework, you only release
>   the public XYZPerson.h header file.

Comment: From what you wrote LibManager can't change aPropertyWritable.

Comment: @kernix Maybe I forgot something? But I implemented this and tested it. In LibManager I could use .aPropertyWritable and it worked fine to set and get .aProperty, while trying to set .aProperty from outside LibManager gave me a compiler error and getting it from the outside returned a copy.

Comment: Did you mean LibClass can't change it? Because that's true.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: Metabble thanks for replying! I want LibManager to hold reference to LibClass, not directly hold reference to the property.

Comment: @kernix Well, in my implementation for testing, LibManager has a reference to a LibClass instance which it hands out through a method. LibClass has the .aProperty, which allows users to only obtain a copy while LibManager can set the property using .aPropertyWritable on its LibClass instance. You can set up the relationships however you want. The above code in the correct files just lets only LibClass and LibManager alter LibClass's aProperty. LibManager doesn't hold reference implicitly to anything; the extension is for LibClass and only reveals the existance of the correct setters/getters.

Comment: Can you please upload project on Github?

Comment: @kernix I edited it to make it clearer. I can't upload to GitHub but it should be easy to make a test project. Just make a new project, make a class. Use the code in the edited answer to add the property. Notice that anything that imports the private header can use the readwrite property while anything that just imports the normal header can't. Obviously whatever type of object you use for the property needs to be copyable.

Comment: Metabble, I'll upload a test  version to Github soon. One question though Why did you return a copy instance of the property? I'm trying to reduce memory usage. Shouldn't it also work without copying the object?

Comment: @kernix It depends on what type the property represents. I'm guessing _aProperty is going to be an object. In that case if we were to just return _aProperty, we'd really be returning a a reference to our own _aProperty. Anything they did to it would affect our copy. So it's a good idea to copy it. If it's very large then I can see why you wouldn't want to... there's more complex ways around copying it I'm sure.

Comment: the whole idea behind my question was to avoid copying; all this return objects need to follow the same solution by being immutable so no changes could be made to them.

Comment: Then... Personally, I'd restructure the whole thing under the proxy pattern. The user would never be able to access the direct model object so we'd not have to worry about unwanted mutation and whatnot. Instead they get an object that acts like a proxy and lets them only access the parts/features of the model I want them to.

Comment: Metabble, proxy won't fit to my needs; Can you log in to the chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85146/discussion-between-metabble-and-kernix).

Answer (score 0):

What about...?

**.h file**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) id lib;
```

**.m file**

```
@interface LibManager ()
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) id lib;
@end

@implementation LibManager
@synthesize lib = _lib;
// ...

- (id)lib
{
    return [_lib copy];
}

- (id)_internal_get_mutable_lib
{
    return _lib;
}
@end
```